# How to render data with Handlebars and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have this html where I need to render the data

**default.hbs**

```
<div class="chart-container" data-action="chartContainer">

  <ul>
   <li class="department">
     <h3>Enterprise</h3>
      <ul class="sections">
        // HERE I NEED TO RENDER THE DATA IN AN <li> TAG
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

and here is the code

```
APP.chartContainer = (function () {
    var Handlebars = window.Handlebars;
    var bindEventsToUI = function () {

    $.getJSON('maindata.json')
        .done(function(data) {
            localStorage.setItem('jsonData', JSON.stringify(data));
        }).fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

        var chartContainerTemplate = $(".chart-container").html();

        var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(chartContainerTemplate);

        var getData = localStorage.getItem('jsonData');

        var iterateObj = $.each(JSON.parse(getData), function(key, val) {
            return val;
        });

        var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(iterateObj[0].enterprise);

        $(".sections").append(theCompiledHtml);

    };

    var init = function (element) {
        bindEventsToUI();
    };

    /**
     * interfaces to public functions
     */
    return {
        init: init
    };

}());
```

the function `iterateObj` returns this

```
[
   {
      "enterprise":[
         {
            "id":"10",
            "name":"Hellen Quesada",
            "role":"Principal Software Engineer"
         },
         {
            "id":"11",
            "name":"Jonathan Chavez",
            "role":"Principal Creative Engineer"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "consumer":[
         {
            "id":"18",
            "name":"Helga Martinez",
            "role":"Production Manager"
         },
         {
            "id":"19",
            "name":"Leroy Bernard",
            "role":"Sr. Software Engineer"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

but all I need to render for now is the enterprise part of the data, that is why in my function I am doing `iterateObj.[0].enterprise` but I am not getting anything in the DOM yet, how do I iterate properly in the over the object in order to get the rendering of the data I need?

What am I missing ?

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous... can't use the response until it is returned. Need to consume that data in the callback

Comment: @charlietfl the thing is: how do I create the template from the JavaScript and then call it from the html?

Answer (score 0):

The template needs to be a script not html. The script can contain the needed html though.

```
<script id="foo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="chart-container" data-action="chartContainer">
    <ul>
        <li class="department">
            <h3>Enterprise</h3>
            <ul class="sections">
                //Not really sure what you want here
                //But access the data like this
                <li>{{enterprise.id}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>
```

Then you compile the template (ie the script):

```
//var chartContainerTemplate = $(".chart-container").html();    
//rename the script to a better id
var chartContainerTemplate = $("#foo").html();
```

Lastly I would highly suggest reading the [docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/). There are ways of looping and accessing data. The above template is very basic.